# XML Parsing - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML that looks like below:

```
declare @xml xml = '<Margins >
<Margin type="type1" currencyCode="currencyCode1">
  <MarginRevenue>1.1</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginRevenue>1.2</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginRevenue>1.3</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginCost>2.1</MarginCost>
  <MarginCost>2.2</MarginCost>
  <MarginCost>2.3</MarginCost>
  <MarginValue>3.1</MarginValue>
  <MarginValue>3.2</MarginValue>
  <MarginValue>3.3</MarginValue>
</Margin>
<Margin type="type2" currencyCode="currencyCode2">
  <MarginRevenue>1.4</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginRevenue>1.5</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginRevenue>1.6</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginCost>2.4</MarginCost>
  <MarginCost>2.5</MarginCost>
  <MarginCost>2.6</MarginCost>
  <MarginValue>3.4</MarginValue>
  <MarginValue>3.5</MarginValue>
  <MarginValue>3.6</MarginValue>
</Margin>
<Margin type="type3" currencyCode="currencyCode3">
  <MarginRevenue>1.7</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginRevenue>1.8</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginRevenue>1.9</MarginRevenue>
  <MarginCost>2.7</MarginCost>
  <MarginCost>2.8</MarginCost>
  <MarginCost>2.9</MarginCost>
  <MarginValue>3.7</MarginValue>
  <MarginValue>3.8</MarginValue>
  <MarginValue>3.9</MarginValue>
</Margin>
```

'

```
SELECT
[Margin_Revenue] = N.value('(MarginRevenue)[1]', 'decimal(15,5)')
,[Margin_Cost] = N.value('(MarginCost)[1]', 'decimal(15,5)')
,[Margin_Value] = N.value('(MarginValue)[1]', 'decimal(15,5)')
FROM
@xml.nodes('Margins/Margin') AS X(N)
```

My requirement is to get all the ,  and  but with Path nodes('Margins/Margin') AS X(N). As of now, I'm getting below only which is actually the first record of each Margin:

```
    Margin_Revenue  Margin_Cost  Margin_Value
    1.10000         2.10000      3.10000
    1.40000         2.40000      3.40000
    1.70000         2.70000      3.70000
```

Comment: adding a desired output will help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `1:n` data at `<Margin>` and again `1:n` data at `<MarginRevenue>`. You need to use `.nodes()` twice via `APPLY`.

```
declare @xml xml = '<Margins>
    <Margin type="type1" currencyCode="currencyCode1">
      <MarginRevenue>1.1</MarginRevenue>
      <MarginRevenue>1.2</MarginRevenue>
      <MarginRevenue>1.3</MarginRevenue>
    </Margin>
    <Margin type="type2" currencyCode="currencyCode2">
      <MarginRevenue>1.4</MarginRevenue>
      <MarginRevenue>1.5</MarginRevenue>
      <MarginRevenue>1.6</MarginRevenue>
    </Margin>
    <Margin type="type3" currencyCode="currencyCode3">
      <MarginRevenue>1.7</MarginRevenue>
      <MarginRevenue>1.8</MarginRevenue>
      <MarginRevenue>1.9</MarginRevenue>
      </Margin>
    </Margins>'

SELECT
 [Margin_Type]         = Marg.value('@type', 'varchar(100)') 
,[Margin_currencyCode] = Marg.value('@currencyCode', 'varchar(100)')
,[Revenue_Value]       = Rev.value('text()[1]','decimal(15,5)') 
FROM
@xml.nodes('Margins/Margin') AS A(Marg)
OUTER APPLY Marg.nodes('MarginRevenue') B(Rev);
```

The result

```
Type    currencyCode    Revenue_Value
-------------------------------------
type1   currencyCode1   1.10000
type1   currencyCode1   1.20000
type1   currencyCode1   1.30000
type2   currencyCode2   1.40000
type2   currencyCode2   1.50000
type2   currencyCode2   1.60000
type3   currencyCode3   1.70000
type3   currencyCode3   1.80000
type3   currencyCode3   1.90000
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @Ajai please avoid chameleon questions... Your "update" is a completely new issue... What you should do instead: Rollback your update and close this question (the initial question seems to be answered) by accepting the best answer and vote on all contributions you like or dislike. Then start a new question and place a link here. Continues...

Comment: @Ajai ... continuing... Start the new qeustion and explain, whether there are always exactly three elements or if their count may vary. Is the only linkage their ordinal position (second rev pairs with second cost and second value)? Might there be missing values or NULL values? How are they linked in such cases? Is there a maximum count of triples? And: If this XML is under your control, you might ask, how to find a better structure...

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenienced caused to you Shnugo. Pls allow me answer your queries. As a standard scenario, these elements can come in any order and also can come in any number of time. In short, the XML is completely dynamic. The only point is Under Margins/Margin, there can be any number of MarginRevenue, MarginCost and MarginValue. Hope I'm clear now.

Comment: @AG7 Above you state the expected output. You provide a list with Revenue, Cost and Value in one row. The only chance to do this, is to place the **first** Revenue, the **first** Cost and the **first** Value in one row, the same with all **second** values and so on. The only way to "map" these elements is their position. What does *any number* mean? What, if there are 5 Revenues, but 3 Costs ans 4 Values? Did you check my answer at your second question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I must say you're a champ in XML/SQL Server trouble shooting and I learnt a lot in just 2 days:). You're right that there can be 5 Revenues, but 3 Costs ans 4 Values. I have modified the queries sent by you so meet my needs. Thanks again for all your help. Other related link for similar problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616198/xml-parsing-in-sql-server

Comment: @AG7, sorry, this is ridiculous... At the linked question there is your question which is of very low quality and absolutely unclear. Provide a realistic XML with varying counts and provide the expected output. Describe the business logic. Furthermore, there are two answers, one of them by me. Did you try them? What is wrong with them?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, required result is not clear for me so please check below query for your required output and let me know if any changes required.

```
SELECT
[Margin_Revenue] = N.value('.', 'decimal(15,5)')
FROM
@xml.nodes('Margins/Margin/MarginRevenue') AS a(N)
```

Comment: Actually the reason why I mentioned the Path

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
[Margin_Revenue] = N.value('(text())[1]', 'decimal(15,5)')
FROM
@xml.nodes('Margins/Margin/MarginRevenue') AS X(N)
```